# Openbox menu.xml: keyboard accelerators possible?

Tags: openbox

I like the right-click menu of Openbox. I've customized things to bring it up by means of the keyboard as well:

```
<keybind key="W-space">
  <action name="ShowMenu">
    <menu>root-menu</menu>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Now, I want to know if it's possible to have keyboard accelerators (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437975/1771119)) so that, with reference to the image, I could, for instance, press `u` to *reconfigure* Openbox.

[image: Openbox right-click menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (and a thank you to folks in the Openbox mailing list).

[image: right-click menu]

Using the menu on the right in the image above as an example,

- pressing the first letter of the menu item will cause that item to launch if there is only **one** item starting with that letter: pressing <kbd>t</kbd> will directly launch Task Manager.
- if more than one menu item starts with the same letter, pressing that letter will cycle through those menu items: pressing <kbd>d</kbd> repeatedly will cycle between `Desktop` and `Download`: once the appropriate choice is highlighted, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>will launch the selected menu item.
- a letter anywhere in the `item label` can be chosen as an "accelerator". For this, `menu.xml` has to be edited. For example, using `<item label="O_bConf">` instead of `<item label="ObConf">` allows one to assign <kbd>b</kbd> as the letter which when pressed will launch ObConf. And <kbd>b</kbd> subsequently is underlined in the menu indicating that it is the accelerator. In other words, an underscore should be placed ahead of the designated letter (which will be underlined once Openbox is reconfigured).